# Healthy way of drawing grid lines in LibGdx

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, rendering, game-engine

So, I wanted to draw a grid in my game and as I was writing it out, it seemed incredibly unusual (at least to me) in terms of efficiency.  I've got two for loops inside a render method which is used to render the game, so it is called very often and fast.

Is this ShapeRenderer portion a red flag?

```
public void render(float deltaTime) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(Color.GRAY.r, Color.GRAY.g, Color.GRAY.b, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);       

    batch.begin();
    this.world.getPlayer().render(deltaTime, batch);
    batch.end();

    // Gridlines
    shape.begin(ShapeType.Line);
    shape.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    for (int i = 0; i < Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 32; i++) {
        shape.line(0, i * 32, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), i * 32);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 32; i++) {
        shape.line(i * 32, 0, i * 32, Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    }
    shape.end();
}
```

Comment: That is not really as bad as it could be... you could have two nested loops making it `O(N^2)` instead of `O(2*N)`. However, if this `shape` object's `line (...)` function translates to a draw call per invocation that is not as efficient as it could be. The underlying `GL_LINES` primitive draws ***unconnected*** line segments in the form of pairs of points. You can easily simplify this to a single draw call using vertex lists (indexed drawing) if it is really bugging you.

Comment: To be honest, even if you used a connected line primitive like `GL_LINE_STRIP`, you could still probably collapse this into a single draw call. It would just require a little bit more sophistication in the order you draw the lines.

Comment: If its not showing up in an benchmarks or profiling, then you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Alright, thanks everybody!  I'll look into the options.

Answer (score 1):

You could use fast, simple and powerful [ImmediateModeRenderer20](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ImmediateModeRenderer20.html).
Please have a look on the following code with PerspectiveCamera:

```
// init primitive renderer
ImmediateModeRenderer20 lineRenderer = new ImmediateModeRenderer20(false, true, 0);

// create atomic method for line
public static void line(float x1, float y1, float z1,
                        float x2, float y2, float z2,
                        float r, float g, float b, float a) {
    lineRenderer.color(r, g, b, a);
    lineRenderer.vertex(x1, y1, z1);
    lineRenderer.color(r, g, b, a);
    lineRenderer.vertex(x2, y2, z2);
}

// method for whole grid
public static void grid(int width, int height) {
    for (int x = 0; x <= width; x++) {
        // draw vertical
        line(x, 0, 0,
                x, 0, -height,
                0, 1, 0, 0);
    }

    for (int y = 0; y <= height; y++) {
        // draw horizontal
        line(0, 0, -y,
                width, 0, -y,
                0, 1, 0, 0);
    }
}

// init 3d camera
PerspectiveCamera perspectiveCamera = new PerspectiveCamera(55, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

// your render loop {
perspectiveCamera.update();
lineRenderer.begin(perspectiveCamera.combined, GL30.GL_LINES);
//... lineRenderer works a lot
grid(10, 10);
//... lineRenderer works a lot
lineRenderer.end();
//}
```

Hope it helps!